# what does "/" mean as a parameter of __init__() of a Python class

Tags: python-3.x

```
class MyClass(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(
        self,
        name: str,
        func: Callable[..., T],
        /,
        *args: Any,
        **kwargs: Any,
    ) -> None:
        # the function does not reference or use the "/" in any way
```

what does the "/" do in this case? Does it have any special meaning or purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that anything *before* the slash, must be passed as positional arguments ([PEP 457](https://peps.python.org/pep-0457/)). You can also see asterisks in arguments. Anything *after* the asterisks must be passed as keyword argument ([PEP 3102](https://peps.python.org/pep-3102/)). [Python documentation about "Special parameters"](https://docs.python.org/3.11/tutorial/controlflow.html#special-parameters)

```py
def func(a, /):
    return a

# Passing as a positional argument
func(1)  # Good
# Passing as a keyword argument
func(a=1)  # TypeError: func() got some positional-only arguments passed as keyword arguments: 'a'
```

```py
#               Positional or keyword
#                         │
#     Positional only     │            ┌─Keyword only
#         ┌──┴───┐     ┌──┴───┐     ┌──┴──┐
def func2(pos_only, /, anything, *, kw_only):
    return pos_only, anything, kw_only

func2(1, 2, kw_only=3)  # Good
func2(1, anything=2, kw_only=3)  # Good
func2(pos_only=1, anything=2, kw_only=3)  # TypeError: func2() got some positional-only arguments passed as keyword arguments: 'pos_only'
func2(1, 2, 3)  # TypeError: func2() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Comment: Perhaps a comment on the `*` instead of just the example would improve this answer. Also, quoting the official documentation / relevant PEP seems appropriate.